# MacOSX programming question here or at apple site?

Tags: support

Should I ask a MacOSX programming question here or at the apple site?
Or both? is cross-posting allowed/discouraged/punished by death?

Answer (score 5):

From [Ask Different’s FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq):

> and it (the question) is **not about** ...
>
> - Apple Developer Programs or programming, with the exception of AppleScript and Automator

So, in general, ask your programming questions on Stack Overflow. AppleScript/Automator are okay on Ask Different, though.

Comment: +1 for not answering `read the FAQ, moron` coz you could've

Comment: @Petruza: But [Moron](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147215/moron) didn't ask the question...

Answer (score 1):

You should ask on Stack Overflow. [Ask Different, the Apple SE site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about using Apple products.